# How to merge three dimensional array in one array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I have the following variable:

```
IEnumerable<Comment>[][] moderatedComments;
/**
* First dimension [] = The repository from where I fetched the comments (Could be more than one repository)
* Second dimension [][] = The moderation operation (There can only be two operations, so this dimension is always of size 2)
* Third dimension IEnumerable<Comment> = The moderated comments for that dimension
*/
```

An example:

```
Comment comment = moderatedComments[1][0].First();
// Repository 1
// Moderation operation 0
// First moderated comment for that repository and operation
```

I want to merge all three dimensions into one (`IEnumerable<Comment>`) containing all the moderated comments, regardless of the repository or moderation operation.

How can this be accomplished with LINQ?

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array, it is just an array of arrays of ...

Comment: @leppie I'm sorry, I don't know the exact word for these types of array, I will gladly accept a title edit

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you're using nested arrays to represent your object graph? You'd probably be better served by adding properties to your `Comment` class.

Comment: I would like not to confuse you with my motives. I think they are irrelevant to this question

Comment: As Asad suggests you may be better off using a custom object and if you want the array like indexing you could always loook into indexer properties. It would be much simpler to work with and further query with Linq as you want to.

Comment: @leppie - this too is multi dimensional. Nothing "just" about it. The standard naming is 'jagged array', but I like array-of-array better too.

Comment: _... are irrelevant to this question_  - we don't always like to help someone to shoot his own foot of. Look for "XY problem" on the meta site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this, please:

```
IEnumerable<Comment>[][] moderatedComments;
var merged = moderatedComments.SelectMany(x => x).SelectMany( x => x );
// merged is IEnumerable<Comment>
```

Comment: That last comment is very helpful but replacing `var` with the exact type is a much stronger statement. Some production code guidelines don't have to be followed in an answer.